# redux combineReducers() is not working in my project with Ducks pattern

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I want to separate modules, so I tried to separate files in the `src/store/modules` directory.

To merge **reducer** modules, I use `combineReducers()` in `modules/index.js`.

Before separating these modules, `modules/index.js` file's code was `modules/board.js`.

Then I added *board.js* file. I moved code of *index.js* to *board.js*. Finally I added `combineReducer()` in *index.js*, but somehow it is not working.

[image: compile error]

[image: Folder Structure]

**src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import App from './containers/App';
import store from './store';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
     rootElement
);
```

**src/containers/BoardContainer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Board from '../components/Board';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as boardActions from '../store/modules/board';

class BoardContainer extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.handleReadBoards();
    }

    render() {
        /* ... */
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        boardList: state.get('boardList')
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        handleReadBoards: () => { dispatch(boardActions.readBoardList()) }
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BoardContainer);
```

**src/store/index.js**

```
// redux
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import reducers from './modules';
// redux middleware
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const store = createStore(reducers,
    compose(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export default store;
```

**src/store/modules/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import board from './board';

export default combineReducers({
  board
});
```

**src/store/modules/board.js**

```
import { createAction, handleActions } from 'redux-actions';
import { Map, List } from 'immutable';

import * as boardApi from '../../lib/api/board';

// Action Types
const READ_BOARD_LIST = 'board/READ_BOARD_LIST';

// Action Creators
export const readBoardList = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const boardList = await boardApi.getBoardList();
        dispatch({
            type: READ_BOARD_LIST,
            payload: boardList
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

// initial state
const initialState = Map({
    boardList: List()
})


// reducer
// export default handleActions({
//     [READ_BOARD_LIST]: (state, action) => {
//         const boardList = state.get('boardList');
//         return state.set('boardList', action.payload.data);
//     },
// }, initialState);

// reducer
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case READ_BOARD_LIST:
            return state.set('boardList', action.payload.data);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reducer now contains submodules. So that you have to state from which module you want to get the data: `state.board.get('boardList')`.

You can try to setup redux tool to easy visualize your data inside redux.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        boardList: state.board.get('boardList')
    };
}
```

Comment: oh.. Thank you really very much. It was very simple problem.. Maybe,i think i has not understood about redux..

Comment: Redux devtool is very useful in my opinion. Just try it and you will see It's easier for you.